# Regex in BigQuery regexp_instr function

Tags: regex, list, google-bigquery

I would like to identify below string via REGEXP_INSTR function on BigQuery:

```
2020-12-31T23:00:00.000Z;15,2021-12-31T23:00:00.000Z;271,2022-12-31T23:00:00.000Z;12,...
```

The input string is a list of couples (datetime/integer value) separated by "," where each couple element is separated by ";".

My first (unsuccessful) iteration was:

```
'^(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}.\\d{3}Z;\\d*)+,?'
```

I don't succeed to properly manage the "list" with possibly uneeded "," after the last element of the list.

Could you help me constructing the regex pattern please ?

Thanks a lot for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the first part, and optionally repeat the whole part preceded by a `,` so it does not match the last comma.

If there can not be a `.` at the end, you can append `$` to the pattern to assert the end of the string.

Note to escape the dot `\.`

```
^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}Z;\d*(?:,\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}Z;\d*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rtCjJ8/1)

With double escaped backslashes

```
^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\.\\d{3}Z;\\d*(?:,\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\.\\d{3}Z;\\d*)*
```